# (AHK) shortening this autohotkey script, possible?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

```
^+a::
soundset +8
soundget vol
tooltip % "volume = " round(vol), 1900, 1000

settimer, removetooltip1, -3000
return
removetooltip1:
tooltip
return

^+s::
soundset -8
soundget vol
tooltip % "volume = " round(vol), 1900, 1000

settimer, removetooltip2, -3000
return
removetooltip2:
tooltip
return

^+c::
soundset, +1,, mute
soundget, mutestate, master, mute
if mutestate=on
tooltip sound = off, 1900, 1000
else
tooltip sound = on, 1900, 1000

settimer, removetooltip3, -3000
return
removetooltip3:
tooltip
return
```

With this script, when you change the volume or mute using hotkeys, small tooltip pops up informing the current volume or mute/unmute status.

It works without any issues, but I wonder if it is possible to combine three of them, maybe by using settimer just once to avoid unnecessary(if any) duplication?

maybe something like this

```
(
^+a::
....
....
^+s::
....
....
^+c::
....
....
)

settimer, removetooltip, -3000
return
removetooltip:
tooltip
return
```

As you may see I am obviously noob. I need help please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one timer for removing the ToolTip:

```
^+a::
    soundset +8
    soundget vol
    tooltip % "volume = " round(vol), 1900, 1000
    settimer, removetooltip, -3000
return

^+s::
    soundset -8
    soundget vol
    tooltip % "volume = " round(vol), 1900, 1000
    settimer, removetooltip, -3000
return

^+c::
    soundset, +1,, mute
    soundget, mutestate, master, mute
    if mutestate=on
        tooltip sound = off, 1900, 1000
    else
        tooltip sound = on, 1900, 1000
    settimer, removetooltip, -3000
return

removetooltip:
    tooltip
return
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Never realized that was this simple :), btw I sometimes panic when I see the word Settimer, thinking it might cause constant running. is it real? I want to minimize using CPU whenever possible :)

Comment: Don't worry. If you look in the Task Manager, the script takes up very little memory and its CPU usage is nill or 0.2  while you're using the hotkeys.

Comment: You can also use ternary operator to shorten a little bit more:   `tooltip, % mutestate = on ? "sound = off" : "sound = on", 1900, 1000` instead of `if\else`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
^+a::
^+s::
    SoundSet, (A_ThisHotkey ~= "a$" ? "+" : "-") 8
    SoundGet, vol
    DisplayToolTip("volume = " round(vol))
return

^+c::
    SoundSet, +1, , mute
    SoundGet, mutestate, master, mute
    DisplayToolTip("sound = " (mutestate = "on" ? "off" : "on"))
return

DisplayToolTip(msg, duration := 3000, x := 1900, y := 1000)
{
    ToolTip, % msg, % x, % y
    SetTimer, RemoveTooltip, % duration * -1
}

RemoveTooltip()
{
    ToolTip
}
```

Basically utilizing [ternaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator#Conditional_assignment) to get rid of duplicate code.
And you might wonder what `A_ThisHotkey ~= "a$"` is.
`~=`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#regex)</sup> is regex shorthand and in the regex we're checking if the last character is <kbd>a</kbd>.
It could just as well be done in a more classic way, e.g. `SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 0) = "a"`, if you prefer.